# MySQLi_fetch_Array skips first row

Tags: php, mysqli

My mysql, i'm trying to call values from the database to be used in a select list. The selection works but skips the first result. I know this is a reasonably common problem but i don't think (at least i cannot see where) i've duplicated the assignment of mysqli_fetch_array which is usually the problem, although the problem is the same as it usually is if that happens.

```
$qselectgamename = "SELECT * FROM game ORDER BY GameName asc";
$rselectgamename = mysqli_query($dbc, $qselectgamename);
if(mysqli_num_rows($rselectgamename) !== false){
     while($rowselectgamename = mysqli_fetch_array($rselectgamename, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          echo '<option value="'.$rowselectgamename['GameID'].'">'.$rowselectgamename['GameName'].'</option>';
     }
} else {
     echo '<option value="0">Please Insert a Game Title first</option>';
}
```

Can anything else i'm doing cause this issue?

Results are 1,2 with 0 dismissed, switch sort to desc and the results are 1,0 with 2 dismissed.

EDIT: I've found the problem, see below.

Comment: I can't see why this code would do this. I've seen many similar questions, and they had an extra call to `mysqli_fetch_array()` before the loop. Are you sure you don't have something like that in the real code?

Comment: BTW, `mysqli_num_rows()` returns a number, never `NULL`. But `0 == NULL` so that test will work.

Comment: certain, doing a CTRL+F and searching for mysqli_fetch_array($rselect brings back one result, the one i've shown you. Yeah i've used mysqli_fetch_array more than once but only once with $rowselectgamename. 
It's also worth saying that i've done this style of select/population elsewhere and it's worked fine.

Comment: Your comparison is really weird. Please change it to `if(mysqli_num_rows($rselectgamename) != 0)`. The way you wrote it, you're not inverting the comparison, you're inverting the number of rows.

Comment: Search for `mysqli_fetch`, maybe you wrote `mysqli_fetch_row` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: the only other use of any mysqli_fetch in the same document (or linked/included documents) is 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM); for a previous query, and not related in any way

Comment: Thank you @F.Müller, but that doesn't really help with my original question. However, i've changed it in my document and will now change it on the starting post.

Comment: `<td class="input"><dropdownlabel><select class="roundedcorners" name="GameName" size="1"
value="'; if(isset($_POST['GameName'])){ echo $_POST['GameName']; } echo '/>';` you're outside of PHP. Unless you've got an `echo '` and not showing it.

Comment: Yeah i did, well before which is why it wasn't in the copy and paste.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: No errors from either, however, having just checked inspect element i'm getting 3 hidden divs created seemingly automatically. Here's the first <div id="u2DCfpwFY9Nd1wRj" class="eC_8JTUF4XjRbburpvgq8" style="display: none;"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

```
<select class="roundedcorners" name="GameName" size="1"
value="'; if(isset($_POST['GameName'])){ echo $_POST['GameName']; } echo '/>';
```

_

```
<select class="roundedcorners" name="GameName" size="1"
value="'; if(isset($_POST['GameName'])){ echo $_POST['GameName']; } echo '"/>';
```

Of course it was because i was echoing the select i didn't see the error (and apparently nobody else did  before i took down the full code). The problem, was the final " was missing. Therefore the value of the select wasn't only the $_POST variable or nothing, it was now value="/> all of option 1 up to the first " and therefore the first option was effectively being absorbed. Goddamn minor errors always mess up my code more than anything else.